# Prove a specific basis exists satisfying certain conditions with an endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm a bit confused about how I should answer this question. If someone could show me how to solve it, I would appreciate it.

Let $F$ be a field and let $T \in End(F^n)$ such that $T(e_j) = e_1 + \ldots + e_n$ for $j = 1, \ldots, n$. We must show:

(i) If $n1_F \neq 0_F$ then $F^n$ has a basis $(k_1,\ldots,k_n)$ such that $T(k_1) = nk_1$ and $T(k_j) = 0$ for $j \neq 1$.

(ii) If $n1_F = 0_F$ then $F^n$ has a basis $(k_1,\ldots,k_n)$ such that $T(k_2) = k_1$ and $T(k_j) = 0$ for $j \neq 2$.

I'm confused about where these properties are coming from and I have no idea how to go about proving them. Any help appreciated!

Helen.

Comment: For intuition's sake, have you tried writing $T$ as a matrix with respect to $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$? Can you compute the eigenvalues of $T$?

Comment: Would it just be a block of all ones?

Answer (score 0):

All the basis vectors go to the same vector  $v=e_1+e_2+\cdots +e_n$. So we see that is $T(v)= nv$.

Comment: Apologies, I cannot see how this answers the question or helps answer the questions. I would appreciate if you could explain, thanks!

Comment: @HelenByrne: you are right, my answer is inadequate. I haven't read the question fully, I realise now. I'll revise it or delete it..